# Global scope variable initialization in google cloud function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-kms

I want to store a secret key using Google Cloud KMS and use it in Google Cloud Function. First I will encrypt my key and store it in environment variable

If I decrypt my secret key like [link](https://github.com/sethvargo/secrets-in-serverless/blob/master/encrypted-envvars/node/index.js), it returns Promise.
Is my variable guaranteed to be finished initializing when my function is deployed and called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of that code snippet and the [corresponding blog post](https://www.sethvargo.com/secrets-in-serverless). For the post history, here's the full snippet the OP is referring to:

```javascript
const cryptoKeyID = process.env.KMS_CRYPTO_KEY_ID;

const kms = require('@google-cloud/kms');
const client = new kms.v1.KeyManagementServiceClient();

let username;
client.decrypt({
  name: cryptoKeyID,
  ciphertext: process.env.DB_USER,
}).then(res => {
  username = res[0].plaintext.toString().trim();
}).catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
});

let password;
client.decrypt({
  name: cryptoKeyID,
  ciphertext: process.env.DB_PASS,
}).then(res => {
  password = res[0].plaintext.toString().trim();
}).catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
});

exports.F = (req, res) => {
  res.send(`${username}:${password}`)
}
```

Because Node is an asynchronous language, there is no guarantee that the variables `username` and `password` are fully initialized before function invocation as-written. In that snippet, I optimized for "decrypt at function boot so each function invocation runs in constant time". In your example, you want to optimize for "the function is fully initialized before invocation" which requires some re-organization of the code.

One possible solution is to move the lookup into a Node function that is invoked when the GCF function is called. For example:

```javascript
const cryptoKeyID = process.env.KMS_CRYPTO_KEY_ID;

const kms = require('@google-cloud/kms');
const client = new kms.v1.KeyManagementServiceClient();

let cache = {};

const decrypt = async (ciphertext) => {
  if (!cache[ciphertext]) {
    const [result] = await client.decrypt({
      name: cryptoKeyID,
      ciphertext: ciphertext,
    });
    cache[ciphertext] = result.plaintext;
  }

  return cache[ciphertext];
}

exports.F = async (req, res) => {
  const username = await decrypt(process.env.DB_USER);
  const password = await decrypt(process.env.DB_PASS);
  res.send(`${username}:${password}`)
}
```

Note that I added a caching layer here, since you probably don't want to decrypt the encrypted blob on each invocation of the function.